# Retrieving achievement image url from itunes connect/game center

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center

I would like to post achievement success on facebook with presentShareDialogWithParams method with the achievement image. But I need an url to the image to be able to post it, so is there a way to get the achievement image url from itunes connect? It works to copy the url from itunes connect manually but I don´t want to save all image url for every achievement.